# Codenarc XML headers

Tags: codenarc

My config header is

```
<ruleset xmlns="http://codenarc.org/ruleset/1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://codenarc.org/ruleset/1.0 http://codenarc.org/ruleset-schema.xsd"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://codenarc.org/ruleset-schema.xsd">
```

The ruleset-schema.xsd is not found. I tried putting http://codenarc.org/ruleset-schema.xsd into my browser and I get a 404 error.

I have codenarc included in my Gradle build file so the jar should be in the class path.

Any ideas?